# Identificando uma troca de página em um sistema web PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, eventos

Quando o usuário entra em uma determinada pagina do sistema, eu faço um update no banco de dados, porém quando o usuário sai dessa pagina eu preciso pegar o evento e fazer um outro update, não estou conseguindo descobrir qual é o evento do usuário sair da pagina e ir até outra, estou usando php no ServerSide.

Comment: Sua dúvida está muito ampla. Está tentando controlar no banco de dados as páginas que o usuário navega? Exemplos de códigos?

Comment: Sim, a grande questão seria, como posso interceptar a movimentação do usuário entre as paginas do meu sistema.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar detectar este evento do botão voltar do navegador com javascript desta forma. Mas não tenho certeza se funcionará plenamente para o propósito que precisa:

```
var url = "http://localhost/seuaplicativo/updateBanco.php";
function updateBanco(e) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            console.log("Sucesso");
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", url+"?url="+encodeURI(document.location), true);
    xhttp.send();
}
window.onpopstate = updateBanco;
```

e no PHP faça algo semelhante à isto:

**updateBanco.php**

```
$url = $_GET["url"];

$banco = mysql_query("localhost", "root", "");
$db = mysql_select_db("controle_de_navegacao");

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tabela (id, url) VALUES (NULL, "{$url}")");

echo $query ? "OK" : "OPS";

?>
```

**O que acontece:** Quando o javascript detectar a função de voltar ou avançar do browser, vai disparar uma requisição ao PHP no servidor que irá fazer o registro que você espera.

Comment: Muito completa a sua resposta, porém só pegando o click no botão voltar do navegador não vai resolver o meu problema.